# load Databricks csv library in pyspark

Tags: csv, apache-spark, pyspark, google-cloud-dataproc

I try to load databricks csv library (cf. https://github.com/databricks/spark-csv) on my spark cluster which I created with Google Dataproc. And all of this using PySpark.

I launch PySpark and I input:

```
spark-submit --packages com.databricks:spark-csv_2.11:1.2.0 --verbose
```

But I get this answer:

```
Using properties file: /usr/lib/spark/conf/spark-defaults.conf
Adding default property: spark.executor.extraJavaOptions=-Xbootclasspath/p:/usr/local/share/google/alpn/alpn-boot-8.1.3.v20150130.jar
Adding default property: spark.history.fs.logDirectory=file:///var/log/spark/events
Adding default property: spark.eventLog.enabled=true
Adding default property: spark.driver.maxResultSize=937m
Adding default property: spark.shuffle.service.enabled=true
Adding default property: spark.yarn.historyServer.address=fb-cluster-1-m:18080
Adding default property: spark.driver.memory=1874m
Adding default property: spark.dynamicAllocation.maxExecutors=100000
Adding default property: spark.scheduler.minRegisteredResourcesRatio=0.0
Adding default property: spark.yarn.am.memory=2176m
Adding default property: spark.driver.extraJavaOptions=-Xbootclasspath/p:/usr/local/share/google/alpn/alpn-boot-8.1.3.v20150130.jar
Adding default property: spark.master=yarn-client
Adding default property: spark.executor.memory=2176m
Adding default property: spark.eventLog.dir=file:///var/log/spark/events
Adding default property: spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled=true
Adding default property: spark.executor.cores=1
Adding default property: spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead=384
Adding default property: spark.dynamicAllocation.minExecutors=1
Adding default property: spark.dynamicAllocation.initialExecutors=100000
Adding default property: spark.akka.frameSize=512
Error: Must specify a primary resource (JAR or Python or R file)
Run with --help for usage help or --verbose for debug output
```

This contradicts the doc https://github.com/databricks/spark-csv combined with the post lebigot at https://github.com/databricks/spark-csv/issues/59

Can someone help me?

Comment: Are you launching a pyspark shell and inputting a `spark-submit` command? Can you try `pyspark --packages com.databricks:spark-csv_2.11:1.2.0` if you have not already? I'm able to run this locally.

Comment: yes I am launching a pyspark shell and inputting spark-submit.  I tried your command and it works, thank you. But is the package installed for good? Or just temporarly downloaded?

Comment: Hey @sweeeeeet, I added an answer with a little more information. Hopefully that helps!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like you were attempting to run a `spark-submit` command within a pyspark shell. It's important to note that the `spark-submit` command is used for [configuring and launching bundled applications](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/submitting-applications.html) on a cluster, whereas the `spark-shell` or `pyspark` commands are used for creating a shell environment with a pre-instantiated `SparkContext` for you to run spark commands in the context of the shell. [Command line usage of the shell](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/programming-guide.html#using-the-shell) is fairly similar to `spark-submit` so in your case, you will have to start your shell like below if you want to include the spark-csv package:

```
pyspark --packages com.databricks:spark-csv_2.11:1.2.0
```

To answer the other questions in your comment, the inputs provided to the `--packages` flag are a list of Maven coordinates that map to jars to be searched for and added to the driver/executor(s) classpath before the job begins. The repositories searched will be your local Maven repository and Maven central by default (as well as any other repositories defined under the `--repositories` flag). If you did not have the package in your local Maven repository before, it will be downloaded from Maven central and then grabbed from local whenever you use the jar again.

Comment: On Dataproc 1.1 (Spark 2.0) when I run `pyspark -- packages com.databricks:spark-csv_2.10:1.0.3` on the master node it returns an error saying `pyspark does not support any application options`